# Convert a 'const wchar_t *' to 'unsigned char *'

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

In C++ is it possible to convert a 'const wchar_t *' to 'unsigned char *'?

How can I do that?

```
wstring dirName;
unsigned char* dirNameA = (unsigned char*)dirName.c_str();

// I am creating a hash from a string
hmac_sha256_init( hash, (unsigned char*)dirName.c_str(), (dirName.length)+1 );
```

Comment: Yes. How do you expect the result to be stored and used? And what does the input look like?

Comment: Should you be calculating the HMAC of the UTF-16 encoded version of your string, or some other character set? (UTF-8, latin1, Windows-1252, etc?) (You will get different HMACs depending on the character encoding, and the answers you have vary on this point!)

Comment: Probably wrong question: Do you want to convert the TYPE or the MEANING? If you want to convert the types you should just use casts as Larry suggested. What you probably REALLY want is to convert a Windows UTF-16 string into something else, and then comes the question people here have asked: What else? SPECIFICALLY? (UTF-8? some ISO-x encoding according to your codepage? etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using reinterpret_cast.  So:

```
unsigned char * dirNameA = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(dirName.c_str());
```

That might not work because c_str returns a const wchar_t *so you can also try:

```
unsigned char * dirNameA = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
                               const_cast<wchar_t *>(dirName.c_str())
                           );
```

This works because hmac_sha256_init should accept a binary blob as its input, so the unicode string contained in dirName is an acceptable hash input.

But there's a bug in your code - the length returned by dirName.length() is a count of characters, not a count of bytes.  That means that passing too few bytes to hmac_sha256_init since you're passing in a unicode string as a binary blob, so you need to multiply (dirName.length()) by 2.

Comment: Note: This will cause the hash to give a different result on different platforms.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, what different platforms do you expect a Windows program to support? ARM (for Win8) is little-endian by default.

Comment: @Don Reba: Even if the program is Windows-only, it might communicate with other systems and expect the HMAC to match.  For example, if you are uploading a file to Amazon S3, if you compute a different HMAC than the server does, your upload will be rejected.

Comment: Simply casting the string is insufficient. The `wchar_t` type may represent a UTF-16 or UTF-32 string (or even another platform-specific encoding). Casting to `char*` could cause multiple strings with the same logical content to produce different results depending on the encoding used or the details thereof. The proper method for this is to use the platform-provided encode/decode functions to guarantee a consistent representation.

Comment: In this case he's passing the string to a function which expects a binary blob.  So he doesn't need to convert to an 8 bit character code.  hmac_sha256_init should accept an arbitrary binary blob.  Answer edited to make that clear.

Comment: Unicode string hashing requires some thinking. (I'm assuming `wstring` is Unicode, if it isn't then the HMAC really stops making sense). Basically U+00C1 Á is equal to U+0041 U+0301 Á and should have the same HMAC for that reason. You'd be best of using Unicode normalization ("NFC")

Comment: @MSalters: You're absolutely right.  And I suspect that the questioner hasn't really thought out what it means to create a hash of a unicode string.  And for those who say "UTF-8", UTF-8 is just a compression algorithm applied to a unicode string - it has the same issues that MSalters brought up.

Comment: @Larry: UTF-8 solves the endianness problem that UTF-16 and UTF-32 have, but it does not solve the Unicode normalization problem that MSalters mentioned.

Comment: @Adam: You're right, it does solve the endian problem.  But given the normalization problem, I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Fortunately Windows supports Unicode Normalization since Vista, and the supports can rather easily be extended to XPSP2/2K3SP1 systems: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert character by character.  There are functions like `wcstombs` to do this.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is necessary. Why couldn't you just use SHA-256 on the raw unicode data? Would it not work for any particular reason, assuming you have the correct length?

Comment: @ChrisLutz The original question asked about converting `const wchar_t *` to `unsigned char *`.  You are correct in that you could just take the hash, but I would be remiss if I didn't mention how to go between wide character strings and character strings

Comment: You're answering the question exactly as asked, but you're missing the real issue here (how to use this function with this string), and potentially giving misleading/dangerous advice. Converting to ANSI first is dangerous, since many unicode strings can collapse to the same value in conversion (you'll end up with ? or some other replacement character), and you'll end up with the same hash for them. For example, if the current code page is a western one, then all Chinese strings of the same length will end up with the same hash, which somewhat defeats the purpose of a hash in the first place.

Comment: @BrendanMcK: Who said anything about ANSI? That's not what `wcstombs` does.

Comment: Apologies, I should have said "any non-Unicode code page" rather than ANSI specifically. You'll hit the same problem with collapsing code points in pretty much any code page. But ANSI vs some MBCS is not the issue here; the key point I raised remains: use wctombs and you end up potentially losing information and ending up with bad or useless hashes - depending on the input data vs current locale.

Comment: wcstombs converts to ansi. In the Windows world ANSI means "the current system code page", whatever that is. So it can be Japanese, or Greek, or Thai, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using WinAPI, use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Not a good idea; see discussion under Foo Bah's answer. Depending on the input string and the code page you convert to, you can end up with input text being collapsed to the replacement character, resulting in low quality hashes. (eg. if you convert to ANSI and the input is Chinese, all strings of the same length will just be similar length strings of the replacement character, resulting in identical hashes.)