# C++: Converting wstring to unsigned char

Tags: c++, casting

I tried to convert a wstring to unsigned char.
I tried _wtoc, but this does not exists.

Is there a conversion in the _wto style?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a 'const wchar\_t \*' to 'unsigned char \*'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624310/convert-a-const-wchar-t-to-unsigned-char)

Comment: The closest I can think of is [wcstombs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs)

Comment: Presumably you mean 'to an array of unsigned chars' What's the input encoding (UCS-2, UTF-16,...)? And what output encoding do you want? (ASCII? UTF-8? EBCDIC?)

Comment: @csl, your duplicate is just about pointer casting for hashing. I suspect the OP wants to convert the string *contents* rather than just cast the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am doing it like this now:

```
wstring sThis=L"12";

unsigned int i;
i=_wtoi(sThis.c_str());

unsigned char c=(unsigned char)i;
```

Answer (score -1):

I do it like this

```
wstring wsWideString
UINT uSize = wsWideString.length();
unsigned char * ptrUChar = new unsigned char[uSize+1];
memset(ptrUChar ,'\0',uSize+1);
for(UINT i=0;i<uSize;i++)
{
ptrUChar [i] = wsWideString[i];
}

//when finished
delete [] ptrUChar ;
ptrUChar  = NULL;
```

Comment: This is pure magic! You are assigning a wide character to a char, gaining you a 50% savings. Great compression ratio! Seriously, though: Worst code I have seen this week. Why use `new` and `memset` when `std::deque` or `std::vector` are there? Why use some made up type (`UINT`) when `size_t` is already there? Etc, etc, etc.