# unsigned char array to wide char array/string

Tags: c++, openssl, widechar

How can/should I cast from a `unsigned char` array to a widechar array `wchar_t` or `std::wstring`? And how can I convert it back to a `unsigned char` array?

Or can OpenSSL produce a widechar hash from `SHA256_Update`?

Comment: Your last statement *almost* showed what you were *actually* trying to do. Clearly you're trying to hash something. Is what you're trying to hash wide char data ? Are you trying to convert the octets returned from the hash API to wide hex chars (`0x010AA02BB` etc...) ? In *either* case, I hope you at-least understand that the result of a hash digest isn't readable asci (or unicode )hex-char data until *you* make it so via some conversion. it's just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I am trying to hash a `std::wstring`, then I want to post it to my server (so convert back to `std::wstring` to post. The hash is my auth token to communicate with the server.

Comment: So you're hashing a `std::wstring` (assuming you're *not* hashing the termination wchar), then converting the resulting hash to a `std::wstring` of char 0..9,a..f (hex chars) to post, and the receiver is then converting that back to octets to validate the hash ? Does that describe your workflow? If so, one of those (the first) may be avoidable depending on how the server's hash value retained for comparison was generated If it was done with wide-data, for example. And I'm assuming you already have a routine that converts raw octets to a `std::wstring` of hex-chars.

Comment: Have you considered usage of MultiByteToWideChar and  WideCharToMultiByte functions? (it is Win API, but perhaps, you are writing for Windows platform)

Comment: @WhozCraig yes thats exactly my workflow. The server script is PHP so it will be working with ascii

Comment: @VolAnd yes funnily enough I am using raw WinAPI so ill look into those functions

Comment: More efficient to use base64 than base16

Comment: The answer you accepted appears not to do what you describe in the question. And also not what you describe in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

unsigned char* temp; // pointer to initial data
// memory allocation and filling
// calculation of string length

wchar_t* wData = new wchar_t[len+1];
mbstowcs(&wData[0], &temp1[0], len);
```

Сoncerning inverse casting look the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624310/convert-a-const-wchar-t-to-unsigned-char) or just use `mbstowcs` once again but with changing places of two first arguments.

Also [WideCharToMultiByte function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) can be useful for Windows development, and setting locale should be considered as well (see some examples).

**UPDATE:**

To calculate length of string pointed by `unsigned char* temp` the following approach can be used:

```
const char* ccp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp);
size_t len = mbstowcs(nullptr, &ccp[0], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
const char* mbstr = "hello";
std::mbstate_t state = std::mbstate_t();
// calc length
int len = 1 + std::mbsrtowcs(nullptr, &mbstr, 0, &state);
std::vector<wchar_t> wstr(len);
std::mbsrtowcs(&wstr[0], &mbstr, wstr.size(), &state);
```

Comment: "The following functions should not be called from multiple threads without synchronization with the std::mbstate_t* argument of a null pointer due to possible data races: std::mbrlen, std::mbrtowc, std::mbsrtowcs, std::mbtowc, std::wcrtomb, std::wcsrtombs, std::wctomb." ... please document what you are posting.

Answer (score 0):

> How can/should I cast from a unsigned char array to a widechar array wchar_t or std::wstring? And how can I convert it back to a unsigned char array?

They are completely different, so you should ***not*** be doing it under most circumstances. If you provide a specific question with real code, than we can probably tell you more.

---

> Or can OpenSSL produce a widechar hash from SHA256_Update?

No, OpenSSL cannot do this. It produces hashes which are binary strings cmposed of bytes, not chars. You are responsible for for presentation details, like narrow/wide character sets or base64 encoding.